# Having a lot of trouble identifying this insect

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

It was found in central Alabama

Comment: This is a true bug nymph; it may be an Assassin Bug (Reduviidae), but I'll admit to uncertainty there.

Comment: A friend of mine, ecologist, also suggested that it's a young Reduvid bug, and that it's supposed to suck blood.

Comment: Its legs are too thin, ain't Reduviidae supposed to be more robust? Maybe it's from an herbivore group.

Comment: I'm inclined to think it's not a Reduviid - those flared legs remind me more of something plant-eaterish; maybe something in the Coreoidea.  The problem is that Heteropterids are a bugger to know well, and that's just the adults.  The juveniles are a real pain.  Better to submit it to one of the ID sites like Bug Guide.

Comment: cool it looks like a cousin of the golden egg bug.

Answer (score 2):

This is a true bug (Heteroptera) larvae as the dorsal scent glands and the wing pockets show (see image below).

I suspect it to be a member of the family [Coreidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coreidae) as it exhibits typical (larval) characteristics of this family: a rhomb shaped body and long legs and antenna.

A reduviid larvae, as some of the commentators suggest, would have a strong, often bow-shaped rostrum (proboscis) that I assume should be visible from the perspective of the photographer. Also, reduviid bugs usually have a relatively long head composed of a long neck and nose.

[image: Coreidae vs Reduviidae]

Compare more images of coreid ([knowyourinsects.org](https://www.knowyourinsects.org/Hemiptera1.html#Coreidae)) and reduviid bugs ([knowyourinsects.org](https://www.knowyourinsects.org/Hemiptera1_Page2.html#Reduviidae)).

---

Image sources (in reading direction):  *Mictis profana* [Graham Wise CC-BY-2.0](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mictis_profana_(16186167367).jpg) | *Coreus marginatus* [AfroBrazilian CC-BY-SA-4.0](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Coreus_marginatus_24.JPG) | *Arilus cristatus* [Judy Gallagher CC-BY-2.0](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Wheel_Bug_nymph_-_Arilus_cristatus,_Jones_Preserve,_Washington,_Virginia_-_29179669286.jpg) | *Rhynocoris annulatus* [Slimguy CC-BY-4.0](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:2018_04_03_Rhynocoris_annulatus_nymph1.jpg)